# AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, streamlit, plotly-express

I am working on a data analysis page for my job and I have been trying to change the format of this bar graph to ascending order. I am using GitHub and Streamlit to deploy the information to a webpage.

This is the piece of code I used to create the actual bar graph:

```
figBARChartJune = px.bar(df_table, x="Issue Sub-Type", y="June 2023", text_auto=True)
figBARChartJune.update_traces(marker_color=['#12e195', '#01cdfe', '#05ffa1', '#b967ff', '#fffb96',
                                        '#001eff', '#e377c2', '#d05037', '#bcbd22', '#17becf',
                                        '#00FFFF', '#BFFF00'])
figBARChartJune.update_layout(
    xaxis_title="Issue Sub-Types",
    yaxis_title="Number of Issues",
    legend_title="Issue Sub-Types",
    font=dict(
        family="Times New Roman, monospace",
        size=12,
        color="RebeccaPurple"
    ),
    title={
        'text': "Total Number of Issues for June 2023",
    }
    )`
```

[Bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRhum.png)

Nothing has been working so far to display the bar graph in ascending order. I put the number text on the stems themselves to show the exact amount.

Please help?

Thanks

Comment: try `fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(autorange="reversed"))`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @DerekO however it only flipped the y-axis. My goal is to have the bar graph ascend from least to greatest, left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the bar graph in itself just plots the data as provided. It is not by default a Pareto (ordered).

You can set this behavior by

```
fig.update_layout(xaxis={'categoryorder':'total descending'})
```

or alternatively

```
fig.update_layout(xaxis={'categoryorder':'total ascending'})
```

https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/

Comment: Thank you so much! @StephanT Really appreciate your help. I didn't think that I needed to actually set a default for this data. You would think by just using the data provided it would automatically format ascending/descending.